# How to subtract Yesterday count by today count when there is mutual items in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to code like this in dax :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using variable inside measure.
Here example

```
Count = var _selectedday = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Date])
var _AccYesterday = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Table'[Account]),'Table'[Date] = _selectedday-1)
return
CALCULATE( COUNTROWS(VALUES('Table'[Account])), NOT('Table'[Account] in _AccYesterday))
```

[image]